# What can possible use of making a class friend and inheriting it also?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, friend

I was going through one of my local libraries and noticed the follwowing:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
        friend class Base; // serves as a factory
    protected:
        pthread_spinlock_t allocLock;
        bool isSafe{ true };

        Derived();
        char *funcA() override;

    public:
        void funcB( bool _in ) override;
        virtual ~Derived();
};
```

I am not able to understand if `Base` has been inherited then why it has been made a `friend` of `Derived`. Also how the comment **serves as a factory** make sense here?

If it were to access `Base` function, `::` operator would have been sufficient.

Is it more related to Design approach?

Comment: Comment that line out, compile, and see what breaks.

Comment: Read up on CRTP. Curiously recurring template pattern.

Comment: @Unapiedra CRTP is when the derived class is a template argument for the base class. Not when the base class is a friend of the derived class.  Sounds similar, but in fact, very different.

Answer (score 0):

Making the base class a friend gives the base class access to the private members of the derived class. It is hard to tell what the reason for this is here without seeing the definition of `class Base`. The comment seems to indicate that the base class has member functions to create objects of the derived classes.

Generally, this is bad design. It is a bad thing when the base class knows about its derived classes at all, and it is even worse when it has access to the derived classes' private members. The dependencies should only go one way: derived classes depend on the base class, not the other way around. In other words, a change in the derived class should not break the base class.

If you need a factory, the right way to do this is to put the creation logic into a separate factory class, not into the base class.

Comment: In theory, the base class can also be the factory. And sometimes, that's convenient.

Comment: In theory, yes. Convenient, maybe. Circular dependency, bad.

Comment: Declaration in base-class, definition after relevant derived classes declared. Easy.

Comment: Easy, as in it will compile.  But then changes to derived classes are likely to break the base class, which is is a bad situation.  A separate factory class results in cleaner separation of creation logic, and thus in more easily maintainable and testable code.

Comment: Changes to the classes the factory-function might construct might necessitate recompiling or even modifying it. Whether it's free-standing, in a dedicated class, or in the base-class doesn't change anything there.